# getFloatTimeDomainData - What exactly does it return?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I can't find out what exactly getFloatTimeDomainData returns ie. what the range of possible values is and what those values are. The specs only say:

> Copies the current down-mixed time-domain (waveform) data into the passed floating-point array.

The values returned seem to range between -1.60 to +1.60 but I can not find out what those values mean.

Comment: If you have 2 questions to ask you will get a better result creating 2 separate questions.

Comment: Changed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It shows how the signal changes with time

The audio signal has a `time-domain`. The values in this domain significy how the audio signal is changing over time. (A derivative of the normal wave-equation).

If a signal were to be constant, there would be no change in the audio signal so I'd suspect that the values returned would all be `0`. The way it changes is given by that time-domain, you could then create a graph of it (which is oscillating usually).

The values signify the change in **amplitude** of the signal. (of all the tracks combined, as is made clear by the statement that it is *down-mixed*.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? My belief is that `getFloatTimeDomainData` returns data like an [AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer), i.e. "non-interleaved IEEE754 32-bit linear PCM with a nominal range between -1 and +1". Are you saying that `getFloatTimeDomainData` returns the _derivative_ of this PCM data?